# Calculate $\int_{-\infty}^0 \int_0^\infty e^{-(x-2y)^2} \ dx \ dy $

Tags: calculus, integration

$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^0 \int_0^\infty e^{-(x-2y)^2} \ dx \ dy $

so we're given the substiution of $ x = 2u + v$  and $y = u - v$ I calculate the jacobian to be $-3$, then from the given intervals I get a new region $ v \leq 0, v \leq u \leq -1/2 v$

So transforming the original question:

$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^0 \int_0^\infty e^{-(x-2y)^2} \ dx \ dy = \int_{-\infty}^0 \int_v^{-1/2 v} e^{-9v^2}(-3) \ du \ dv= \int_{-\infty}^0 (\frac{9}{2}ve^{-9v^2}) \ dv = \dfrac{9}{2} \left [ \dfrac{-1}{18}e^{-9v^2} \right ]_{-\infty}^0 = - 1/4$ However, entering this on wolframalpha I get an answer of 1/4 - Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: The transformation formula uses the _absolute value_ of the Jacobian.

Comment: @DanielFischer Damnit, forgot about that. Could you explain why? I asked my lecturer but he said it'd be covered in later analysis courses (as this is a methods class).

Comment: In the Riemann integral over an interval, we have the orientation in the integral limits, $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = - \int_b^a f(x)\,dx$. There, upon substitution, we keep the sign of the derivative, since we substitute the integral limits in place, the sign can then be used to swap the limits to have an integral with the usual orientation. With the Lebesgue integral, or higher-dimensional Riemann integral, the domain of intergation is taken with its natural orientation, so only the volume-change counts, not a possible reversal of orientation.